# With IntelliJ IDEA, how can I exclude a directory from a project without opening the IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea

For reasons beyond my control, many of my project directories must contain several symbolic links to directories containing huge numbers of files (potentially hundreds of thousands) on a network file system.  These are located parallel to the root `pom.xml`.

When IntelliJ attempts to index these directories, it freezes up (I expect it would finish eventually).  Often I can mark these directories as excluded so IntelliJ will not index them. However, these directories are sometimes created after initial project import.  If IntelliJ catches them before I can mark them as excluded, it freezes. Worse, when I restart and attempt to open the project, it immediately freezes again.

How can I mark that these directories should be excluded without actually opening the project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the project file directly to exclude these directories.  Find the `.iml` file for your project. Add `excludeFolder` elements under the `content` element like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
    <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_6" inherit-compiler-output="false">
      <!-- other things will be here -->
      <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
        <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/directoryToExclude" />
        <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
      </content>
      <!-- etc -->
```